unknown blob error in private docker registry under nginx reverse proxy
I'm trying to run a private docker registry in a virtual machine, as a previous step to deploy it in a VPS.
When I run the registry in local, with this command, everything seems to work fine:
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 --name docker_registry -e REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET=banana registry:latest

But when I do the same in the virtual machine with a domain name, with nginx as a reverse proxy, it gives me an unknown blob error. I've been checking the logs but can't figure out what is happening.
This is the nginx configuration. The certificates are self-signed, but I downloaded the certificate to /etc/docker/certs.d, and it seems to work fine:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.of.the.registry;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.of.the.registry;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/privkey.pem;

    # SSL Configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    client_max_body_size 2G;

    # Docker registry reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # Maximum file upload size
        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
}

This is the /etc/docker/registry/config.yml file, it should be the default one:
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3

This is the environment of the docker machine:
HOSTNAME=621def0df250
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
OLDPWD=/
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET=banana
PWD=/etc/docker/registry

And these are the logs, in json format:
https://gist.github.com/AlvaroMaceda/903eeb84513150b16f4a2cada720b6a8
Some help would be appreciated, I don't really know what to do.

It looks like you've set up a private Docker registry and are encountering an "unknown blob" error when pushing images.
To fix this, make sure Nginx is correctly forwarding the requests; verify the Docker registry configuration and file permissions; confirm that the client trusts the self-signed certificate and analyze the logs for detailed error information.
Make sure that Nginx is correctly forwarding requests to the Docker registry and check the Nginx logs for any errors or misconfigurations:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.of.the.registry;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    client_max_body_size 2G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
}

Make sure the docker registry configuration file (/etc/docker/registry/config.yml) is correctly set up, and verify the storage path and permissions.
Based on your config:
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3

Make sure that the self-signed certificate is correctly installed on the client machine. Docker requires the CA certificate to be placed in /etc/docker/certs.d/<your_registry_domain>/ca.crt.
You mentioned you've done this, but recheck the permissions and contents.
Make sure that docker is correctly configured to trust your self-signed certificate.
Add or verify the following in your Docker daemon configuration (/etc/docker/daemon.json):
{
  "insecure-registries": ["domain.of.the.registry"]
}

Restart the docker daemon after making changes:
sudo systemctl restart docker

The logs indicate blob unknown to registry. This typically means the Docker client is trying to reference a blob that the registry cannot find.
This can happen due to:
Incomplete push: Ensure the push operation completed successfully.
Permission issues: Verify the permissions of the storage directory (/var/lib/registry).
As a last resort, you might want to reinitialize the registry data directory. Note: This will delete all your current images in the registry.
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/registry/*
sudo docker restart docker_registry

Run the docker registry directly without Nginx and see if the issue persists.
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 --name docker_registry -e REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET=banana registry:latest

Push an image to local registry:
docker tag <your_image> localhost:5000/my-test
docker push localhost:5000/my-test

If that works, the issue might be with Nginx or certificates.

The problem was with the nginx configuration. I think the important part is this, but I haven't tested:
proxy_ssl_verify on;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/fullchain.pem;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

This is the full configuration file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.of.the.registry;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name {{ registry_domain }};

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/privkey.pem;

    # Maximum file upload size
    client_max_body_size 2G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /v2/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # These headers are required for Docker to trust the registry
        # certificate and enable client-side certificate validation
        proxy_ssl_verify on;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.of.the.registry/fullchain.pem;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    }
}

